# Undefined error from terminal when running twitter bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, terminal, backend

I made this twitter bot in Javascript following a few tutorials.

Does anyone know why I keep getting this error in terminal I try to run it by typing: node bot.js?

```
console.log(err[0].message);
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
    at /Users/stanleyjeong/Desktop/_CODING/twitter-bots/bot-take2/bot.js:20:36
    at Request._callback (/Users/stanleyjeong/Desktop/_CODING/twitter-bots/bot-take2/node_modules/twitter/lib/twitter.js:220:14)
    at Request.self.callback (/Users/stanleyjeong/Desktop/_CODING/twitter-bots/bot-take2/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/Users/stanleyjeong/Desktop/_CODING/twitter-bots/bot-take2/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Users/stanleyjeong/Desktop/_CODING/twitter-bots/bot-take2/node_modules/request/request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1201:12)
```

Here is my bot JS file:

```
const Twitter = require('twitter');
const config = require('./config.js')

// configuration is set up.
const Tweet = new Twitter(config);

    const params = {
        q: '#funkydancing OR #polyrhythms OR #puppies',      // hashtag I'm searching for
        count: 10,              // number of tweets I'd like returned to me. NOTE: it's best practice to keep the search count number to 10 or under. This prevents spam abuse with your Twitter account, hitting the retweet limit too quickly, and getting your account suspended.
        result_type: 'recent',  // only the most recent results
        lang: 'en'              // only in english. 
    }

Tweet.get('search/tweets', params, function(err, data, response) {
    if(!err){
        for(let i = 0; i < data.statuses.length; i++){
            let id = { id: data.statuses[i].id_str }
            Tweet.post('statuses/retweet', id, function(err, response){
              if(err){
                console.log(err[0].message);
              }
              else{
                let username = response.user.screen_name;
                let tweetId = response.id_str;
                console.log('Retweeted: ', `https://twitter.com/${username}/status/${tweetId}`)
              }
            });
          }
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
```

The config.js file just has an object containing my API keys and secret keys.

FYI, I installed the twitter dependency, and my API keys and secret keys are recent.

Thank you!

Comment: err is not an array. just `console.log(err)` / `console.log(err.message)`

Comment: That's probably it. Try console.log error first and see what that gives you. If it is not of an array type, then that undefined error will be thrown.

Comment: awesome. that was it. Thank you both for your help!!